Entropy of dielectric in Capacitor?
So I am learning about dielectrics, and my professor was saying that if we connect capacitor containing dielectric to a DC source, theoretically it should produce little to no heat (the only heat generated should be from minor disturbance of charges and rotation of dipoles as they realign themselves).
I was thinking that in absence of an external electric field, the dipoles are randomly arranged and so they must constitute a higher entropy state. But as they realign themselves, they all form an ordered arrangement which constitute a lower entropy state. So shouldn't temperature decrease ?(I am definitely doing some misunderstanding here but can't figure out what). Also I got another doubt, if entropy of dielectric reduces, how entropy of surroundings increase. Like I really am getting confused in many things, so I really want to get them cleared; thanks for help.

A decrease or increase in temperature is not necessary for there to be a decrease or increase in entropy. For example, the freezing of water at constant temperature reduces its entropy entropy.

This is called the electrocaloric effect and para- and ferro- magnetic materials also show similar behavior. It can be shown that, see Eq (5) and the references therein, with $\mathbf D=\epsilon_0 \mathbf E +\mathbf P$ the entropy in an EM field is
$$S= \int_{V} dV \int_{0}^{D} \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{P}}{\partial T}\right)_{T,D}\cdot \textrm{d}\mathbf{D}
+\int_{V}dV\int_{0}^{B}\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{M}}{\partial T}\right)_{T,B}\cdot \textrm{d}\mathbf{B}$$ and just looking at the dielectric contribution, the spatial density of the entropy is
$$\tilde s= \int_{0}^{\mathbf E} \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{P}}{\partial T}\right)_{T, \mathbf{e}}\cdot \textrm{d}\mathbf{e} \tag{1}$$
In case of a linear material $\mathbf P = \chi \mathbf E$ you get the entropy's dependence on temperature sensitivity of the susceptibility as
$$\frac{d \tilde s}{dE} = \frac{1}{\epsilon_0} \left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{\chi}}{\partial T}\right)E \tag{2}.$$
If you integrate this from $0$ to $E$ you have the entropy density $\tilde s(E)$ as
$$\tilde s =\tilde s_0 + \frac{1}{2\epsilon_0} \left(\frac{\partial\mathbf{\chi}}{\partial T}\right)E^2 \tag{3}.$$
Depending on the sign of $\frac{\partial\mathbf{\chi}}{\partial T}$ the entropy either increases or decreases as the electric field changes.
